# Plot a confusion matrix in r showing percentages (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, confusion-matrix

So I have these two columns which I want to turn into a confusion matrix

```
faceEmotion
neutral
sad
happy
disgusted
angry
fearful
neutral
sad
sad
happy
happy
fearful
```

and

```
faceEmotionGuess
neutral
sad
happy
disgusted
angry
fearful
sad
disgusted
happy
happy
sad
neutral
```

I saw this [beautiful confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46gdh.jpg) made with ggplot but I have no idea of how he made it. Google hasn't been too helpful.

Thanks for any sort of help you may provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data is obviously not as rich as the sample data from which the desired image was created, but you could create a similar plot from your data like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

tab <- table(df$faceEmotion, df$faceEmotionGuess)
tab <- tab / rowSums(tab)
tab <- as.data.frame(tab, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
tab$Var2 <- factor(tab$Var2, rev(levels(tab$Var2)))

ggplot(tab, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Freq))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#3575b5") +
  labs(x = "Emotion", y = "Guess", title = "Confusion matrix of emotions",
       fill = "Select") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25, hjust = 0.5, 
                                  margin = margin(20, 0, 20, 0)),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14, margin = margin(0, 20, 10, 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20), size = 18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 20, 0, 10), size = 18))
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(faceEmotion = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("angry", "disgusted", 
"fearful", "happy", "neutral", "sad"), class = "factor"), 
faceEmotionGuess = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("angry", 
"disgusted", "fearful", "happy", "neutral", "sad"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df
#>    faceEmotion faceEmotionGuess
#> 1      neutral          neutral
#> 2          sad              sad
#> 3        happy            happy
#> 4    disgusted        disgusted
#> 5        angry            angry
#> 6      fearful          fearful
#> 7      neutral              sad
#> 8          sad        disgusted
#> 9          sad            happy
#> 10       happy            happy
#> 11       happy              sad
#> 12     fearful          neutral
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Very, very helpful!
But why is the percentages showing > 100%?
And yes, the data provided here was just a section of my dataframe

Comment: @JørgenHøjlundwibe see my update - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. You are a legend. Thank you so much! I've been sitting for hours with this and now I can carry on.